# Did Kashpirovsky successfully heal people through psychic healing?

Tags: healthcare, russia, psychics

Anatoly Kashpirovsky ([Russian Wikipedia](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9,_%D0%90%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%9C%D0%B8%D1%85%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87), [English Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anatoly_Kashpirovsky)) was a super-famous Russian celebrity, who, in the late '80s, went on Soviet TV and claimed he psychically healed people, and provided pain-relief psycically during surgery over a teleconference.

The Russian Wikipedia article linked has several specific claims over his healing results.

Did any reliable scientific investigation confirm any of the effects of his claimed healing?

> - 31 марта 1988 года был проведён телемост «Москва-Киев». Заявлялось, что во время телемоста Москва-Киев 31 марта 1988 года впервые в мире было проведено дистанционное обезболивание хирургической операции резекция молочной железы у пациентки Любови Грабовской при поддержке и участии первого на Украине академика-онколога Н. М. Бондаря и доктора медицинских наук, профессора, врача-хирурга В. И. Королёва.
>
>   - March 31, 1988 was held a teleconference "Moscow-Kiev". It was stated that ... for the first time in the world they had held **remote anesthesia** using surgical resection of breast cancer in a patient Lyubov Grabowska; with the support and participation of the first Ukrainian academician oncologist N. Bondar and doctor of medical sciences, professor, surgeon V.I. Korolev.
> - В том же году на украинском телевидении Анатолий Кашпировский провёл пять телевизионных передач для детей с целью избавления их от энуреза. Заявлялось, что результатом стало оздоровление за суммарное телевизионное время 3 часа 15 минут 72 % детского населения Украины, то есть около 800 тысяч детей.
>
>   - In the same year on the Ukrainian television Anatoly Kashpirovsky led  five television programs for children in order to rid them from enuresis. It claimed that the result was the improvement (during the total television time 3 hours 15 minutes) of 72% of the child population of Ukraine, which is about 800 thousand children.
> - Через год в ночь на 2 марта 1989 года состоялся вызвавший еще большую сенсацию телемост «Киев-Тбилиси» с дистанционным обезболиванием теперь уже двух полостных операций одновременно с участием выдающегося хирурга, член-корреспондента АМН СССР, профессора, Почетного директора Тбилисского НИИ экспериментальной и клинической хирургии им. академика Эристави, заслуженного деятеля науки Грузии академика Г. Д. Иоселиани, хирургов З.Мегрелишвили и Г.Бочаидзе. Разрезы брюшной полости в ходе операций по удалению вентральных грыж у пациенток О. Б. Игнатовой и Л. Н. Юршовой составляли 25 и 40 сантиметров соответственно. «Это не чудо — это сверхчудо!» — так комментировал фантастичность происходящего академик Г. Д. Иоселиани.
>
>   - A year later, on the night of 2 March 1989 they had even more sensational teleconference "Kiev-Tbilisi"; with **remote anesthesia** now applied to two abdominal operations at the same time with the participation of prominent surgeon, corresponding member of the Academy of Medical Sciences of the USSR, professor, honorary director of the Eristavi Tbilisi Institute of Experimental and Clinical Surgery, honored scientist of Georgia Academician D. Ioseliani, surgeons and G.Bochaidze and Z.Megrelishvili.
>       Abdominal incision during removal operations for ventral hernias in patients O.B. Ignatova and L.N. Yurshovoy were 25 and 40 centimeters respectively.   "This is not a miracle - it super-miracle!" - So commented on the fantastic happening Academician D. Ioseliani.
> - Далее в 1989 году на Центральном телевидении были проведены шесть передач «Сеансы здоровья врача-психотерапевта Анатолия Кашпировского», в ходе которых А. М. Кашпировский якобы осуществил беспрецедентное по своим масштабам излечение от самых различных заболеваний около 10 миллионов человек всего за 6 часов телевизионного эфира. Первая телепередача, согласно телепрограмме, вышла в эфир 8 октября 1989 года по Первой программе (затем выходила каждое воскресенье, один раз в две недели).
>
>   - Then in 1989 at the Central Television were held six TV shows "Health sessions of psychotherapist Anatoly Kashpirovsky" in which A.M. Kashpirovskiy allegedly carried out on an unprecedented scale recovery from a wide variety of diseases for about 10 million people in just 6 hours of television time. The first television program aired on October 8, 1989 ... (then went out every Sunday, once every two weeks).

<sub>Russian translation by Google Translate, polished up by myself</sub>

Comment: *The Russian Wikipedia article linked has several specific claims over his healing results*, could you cite and translate some of those specific claims?

Comment: @gerrit - ugh. Cleaning up Google Translate for medical terminology is weird. Done.

Comment: Seems like the Soviet Union lacked a [James Randi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/James_Randi).

Answer (score -1):

Kashpirovsky made many patients feel better, but there's only one documented proof of the effectiveness of his hypnosis, but the numerous statements of the grateful followers. The only scientific evidence of the "power" of Kashpirovsky is the TV bridge, where [Georgy Ioseliani](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%98%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8,_%D0%94%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4_%D0%93%D0%B5%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87), a famous surgeon, risking his scientific career (being skeptical about the abilities of Kashpirovsky) has held a surgery of the stomach tumor without anesthesia (due to the contraindications) via a TV bridge with Kashpirovsky, who claimed to provide anesthetic effect to the patient through talking to the patient (hypnosis) during the whole surgery for three hours. [The patient is conscious and seems to not experience any discomfort](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=djni-2FRNjs&nohtml5=False)

> Academician Georgi Ioseliani: "I had to face the fact: Kashpirovskiy
>   will inhibit the pain syndrome of two patients via the TV bridge, and
>   I will have to operate one of the patients. The patients were very
>   allergic to all medications, and Lesia had gone through clinical death
>   after the orevious operation. Of course, we understood the risks if
>   Kashpirovskiy couldn't cope with the patients. Then it would have been
>   the case for the work of the anesthetists, but I don't know, if Lesya
>   would have survived the operation  without Kashpirovsky."

In addition, as a part of personal anecdote, I was put in front of TV because of the disturbing big scar on a chin and it healed much quicker, than the doctor expected. It's one of the personal evidences of the healing power of suggestion